# Condition within condition java

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, chatbot

I'm new to this website and as well as java.

Can anyone help me find out why some part of the program is not working even though there's no red dots?

I've put comment using // on the lines not working.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ChatterBot {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String firstName, work, sex = null;
    int age;
    firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hello, my name is Chatterbox. What is your name?");
    if (firstName.toLowerCase().contains("name".toLowerCase())) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome " + firstName.substring(firstName.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1) + "!");
        sex = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Is " + firstName.substring(firstName.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1)
                + " a guy name or a woman name? (type stop to end conversation)");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome " + firstName + "!");
        sex = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Is " + firstName + " a guy name or a woman name (type stop to end conversation)");
    }

    while (true)
        if (sex.toLowerCase().contains("guy".toLowerCase())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome friend");
            work = JOptionPane
                    .showInputDialog("Would you like to talk about work or do you want to hear a cool story?");
            if (work.toLowerCase().contains("work".toLowerCase())) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Interesting");
                break;

            } else if (work.toLowerCase().contains("story".toLowerCase())) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hola");
                break;
            } else if (sex.toLowerCase().contains("woman".toLowerCase())) { 
//when I type woman nothing happens but the else if below for "stop" works. 
                age = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How old are you?"));
                if (age >= 18 && age <= 40) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dayummm");
                } else if (age > 40) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I don't like no cougar!");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I ain't no pedo. Bye!");
                }
            }

            break;
        } else if (sex.toLowerCase().contains("stop".toLowerCase())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Have a nice day.");
            break;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goodbye");
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: A debugger can help you

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a "we debug your program for your" service. And you know what helps: when joining a *new* place, you *first* learn about the rules at that place, instead of blindly dumping content. In that sense: please A) delete this "question" B) read up the [help] and learn how to ask a better question ;-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your `if (sex.toLowerCase().contains("woman".toLowerCase()))` block is nested inside the `if (sex.toLowerCase().contains("guy".toLowerCase()))` block, but they should be at the same level :

```
  if (sex.toLowerCase().contains("guy".toLowerCase())) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome friend");
        work = JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Would you like to talk about work or do you want to hear a cool story?");
        if (work.toLowerCase().contains("work".toLowerCase())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Interesting");
            break;

        } else if (work.toLowerCase().contains("story".toLowerCase())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hola");
            break;
        } 

        break;
    } else if (sex.toLowerCase().contains("woman".toLowerCase())) { 
           //when I type woman nothing happens but the else if below for "stop" works. 
            age = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How old are you?"));
            if (age >= 18 && age <= 40) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dayummm");
            } else if (age > 40) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I don't like no cougar!");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I ain't no pedo. Bye!");
            }
    } else if (sex.toLowerCase().contains("stop".toLowerCase())) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Have a nice day.");
        break;
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Goodbye");
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Just writing the same answer - will stop ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your if statements aren't in order, You are missing one character `}` to close if and remove `}`

```
 } else if (sex.toLowerCase().contains("woman".toLowerCase())) { 
//when I type woman nothing happens but the else if below for "stop" works. 
                age = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How old are you?"));
                if (age >= 18 && age <= 40) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dayummm");
                } else if (age > 40) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I don't like no cougar!");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I ain't no pedo. Bye!");
                }


            break;
        }
```

Also suggestion: introduce variable to prevent duplicate code

```
 String sex = sex.toLowerCase()
 String work = work.toLowerCase()
```

Also you can remove toLowerCase() on lower case values as `"story".toLowerCase()`

Comment: I didn't write compile error, just fixed the if statements. I'll write more details

Comment: Sorry I was not sure of your wording